# Returning single String from array

Tags: java

Im trying to write simple game in libGDX, but this problem stops whole process of creating that game. 
Here is two classes.

```
public class Question {

private static float getFontX() {
    return Assets.font.getBounds(Database.getText()).width / 2;
}

private static float getFontY() {
    return Assets.font.getBounds(Database.getText()).height / 2;
}

public static void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {

    Assets.font.draw(batch, Database.getText(),
                             TOFMain.SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - getFontX(),
                             getFontY() + 250 + TOFMain.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2);
           //drawing some text from database on screen in the middle of screen;

}
```

and the second class is Database it contains questions

```
public class Database {

private static String questions[] = new String[2];
{
    questions[0] = "Some question1";
    questions[1] = "Some question2";
}

static public String getText() {
    return questions[0];
}
}
```

There is a problem in

```
return questions[0]
```

because if I write there for example

```
return "This will work";
```

everything is ok.

Comment: what libgdx has to do with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your initialisation block to static initialisation block.

```
static {
    questions[0] = "Some question1";
    questions[1] = "Some question2";
}
```

If you won't create new instance of Database class like:

```
Database db = new Database();
```

dynamic initialisation block won't be called. This is reason why you need to use static initialisation block that is called with class.

Comment: Thanks, simple mistake. I know that :P

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the array in `Database` class as:

```
public class Database {

private static String questions[] = new String[]{
    "Some question1", "Some question2"
};


static public String getText() {
    return questions[0];
}

}
```

Then it returns the `String` you want.

Comment: Yeah I know but for me my form of code is more readable :) and this was the reason for the error :S